.htaccess Add Trailing Slash at the end in of page already transformed from /page.html to /page
I've got a website linked in plain html. I found this code to transform the links and remove the .html extension
This work perfect
#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

For some reason when I add a trailing slash to a page, like page.html/ it gives me the error "page not found".
The question is how can I improve the code to accept trailing slashes at the end of urls already transformed from page.html to page from page.html to page?

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f obviously can't match any more, when you request page/- because page/.html doesn't exist. But if you capture the page part in your RewriteRule pattern, and allow for an optional slash after that - then you can use the back reference to the captured match in your RewriteCond. You'd have to check if %1 -f works already, otherwise you might need to prefix it with the DOCUMENT_ROOT variable.
